# Offer a bounty for an action outside SFF?

Tags: discussion

In particular regards to this question: [Did the Peverell brothers attend Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120014/did-the-peverell-brothers-attend-hogwarts)

I have received two comments that seem to believe I could get an answer by using Twitter to pose the question to JK Rowling.

I do not have a Twitter account nor do I want to create one.

My question is; could I start a bounty and then award to a person who does have Twitter, poses the question to Twitter, and then posts the proof as answer here?

Comment: Why not?.......

Comment: we have asked her multiple questions on twitter, and to date we've(the users of this site) had 0 responses from her AFAIK.

Comment: @Himarm, Yes, I would think that just by the shear number of questions she is asked would make the % of an individual question asked very small.  Removing context though, would it be against any SE rules to offer a bounty for actions outside the site?

Comment: @Skooba you shouldnt put a bounty up asking someone to tweet, because once you start the bounty, whether anyone  gets a responce or not after 7 days you have to award it. So if someone does ask, AND gets a responce, you can then give them a bounty for going above and beyond. essentially using a bounty with "ask the author" as the intent is wasteful.

Comment: Easy solution. Don't give a bounty for tweeting, give a bounty for answering it properly (possibly by tweeting and then answering). Bounties for good answers are the exact use case for what they exist, so there shouldn't be any problem with offering one for a good (possibly Twitter-based) answer. You're not rewarding an action "outside of SFF" with that, since writing a good answer always happens inside the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can award bounties for whatever you see fit, so long as it isn't meant to be a way to simply build up the rep for a specific user. That is, you're not just trying to transfer a lot of rep to one person over the course of many bounties. That's similar to serial upvoting. (Although, I haven't found this particular policy written down, yet, I assume it's true, as would any other stances against intentional abuse or exploitation would be.)

You could edit your question to specify you'd be willing to award a bounty to any user that could get a response for JKR on Twitter, but those users would have to trust that you'd actually do it. However, your low rep score (meaning, you have little to give), and your account age could lead people to be wary of such claims. I'm not saying your untrustworthy!

Of course, if you offer a bounty *now*, there's a good chance that no one will get a response in time, and the bounty will go to a user that's answered based on the [award system policies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: 1) Transferring rep via bounties is dissimilar to serial upvoting in that no new rep is created in the system by doing so. Although frowned upon, it doesn't appear to be penalised unless new privileges are granted by doing so (e.g. bountying a 1000-rep user up to a 5000-rep user). 2) Why would people be "wary" of such an offer from Skooba? 3) Bounties are only auto-awarded if someone answers *during the time the bounty is open* and gets sufficient votes in that time.

Comment: @rand 1) New rep is created by the person offering bounties to a single user over and over. It's like having a sock puppet that's just run by a second person. If there's no rule against it, I find it silly. A user could transfer all their rep to their friend before quitting. 2) I'm not going to take a "promise" from a new user, myself. If the bounty is actually offered first, then yes. 3) That's why I linked the policy.